# Inequality involving sum of maximum

Tags: inequality, summation

I just have a short question:

I was wondering whether $ \sum_{i \in I} \max\lbrace 0, a_i-b_i \rbrace \ge \max_{i \in I} \lbrace a_i \rbrace - \min_{i \in I} \lbrace b_i \rbrace $ is true for any $ a_i,b_i \in [0,1] $, where $ I $ is a finite index set.

Can you help me to find a proof or a counterexample?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Sorry for not providing any additional material. In fact, this is an isolated question I found on an old exercise sheet. So, unfortunately, there is no backstory, and my hope was that keeping the question as simple as possible could also motivate the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the statement is false, for example, if $\#I=2$ and $a_1=1/4$, $a_2=3/4$, $b_1=1/2$ and $b_2=3/4$,
$ \sum_{i \in I} \max\lbrace 0, a_i-b_i \rbrace =0$, but $ \max_{i \in I} \lbrace a_i \rbrace - \min_{i \in I} \lbrace b_i \rbrace = 3/4-1/2 = 1/4>0.$

Comment: Ok, sorry, it was too easy to see it. I always played with some different numbers and did not find counterexamples.

Comment: @MartinR: Don't we have equality when $ a_1=a_2=1 $, $ b_1=0 $, and $ b_2=1 $? Or did I understand it wrong?

Comment: @Phil: Sorry, I meant $a_1= b_1 = 0$ and $a_2=b_2=1$. Then the LHS is zero, and the RHS  is $1-0 = 0$.